# Passing Php array as Javascript array values

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I am adding a Highcharts for my project.I want to populate Javascript array from database values..

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body -%}
 <div class="page-header">
     Supporters
 </div>
 <div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Population (millions)'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Population',

                /*data: [
                    ['Shanghai', 23.7],
                    ['Lagos', 16.1],
                    ['Instanbul', 14.2],
                    ['Karachi', 14.0],
                    ['Mumbai', 12.5],
                    ['Moscow', 12.1],
                    ['São Paulo', 11.8],
                    ['Beijing', 11.7],
                    ['Guangzhou', 11.1],
                    ['Delhi', 11.1],
                    ['Shenzhen', 10.5],
                    ['Seoul', 10.4],
                    ['Jakarta', 10.0],
                    ['Kinshasa', 9.3],
                    ['Tianjin', 9.3],
                    ['Tokyo', 9.0],
                    ['Cairo', 8.9],
                    ['Dhaka', 8.9],
                    ['Mexico City', 8.9],
                    ['Lima', 8.9]
                ],*/
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: -90,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'right',
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                    y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to replace those dummy data from real values in database.I created a method that will call Doctrine and retrieve thos records.So far, I can successfully retrieve those data using Symfony's dump tool.

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $province = $em->getRepository('DuterteBundle:Grps')->createQueryBuilder('g')
      // ->join('p.region', 'r')
      // ->where('r.id =:x')
      // ->setParameter('x', 1)
       ->orderBy('g.name', 'ASC')
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult();

   // $dat = $this->container->get('duterte.twig.province_voters_extension');
    $datas = array();//initialise array
        foreach ($province as $r) {

           // $datas[] = array($r->getName(),(int)$dat->a($r->getId()),$r->getName());
            $datas[] = array($r->getName(),123);
        }

    $data = $datas;
    echo '<pre>';
    \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($data);
    echo '</pre>';
    return $this->render('GraphBundle:Default:group.html.twig', array(
        'data' => $data
    ));
```

Variable data contains real data which I want to populate in Javascript data variable.How to achieve this?I tried to use this

```
 <script>
  ...
   data= <?php $data ?>

   /*data: [
            ['Shanghai', 23.7],
            ['Lagos', 16.1],
            ['Instanbul', 14.2],
            ['Karachi', 14.0],
            ['Mumbai', 12.5],
    */


 </script>
```

Doesn't work in Twig environment

Comment: Did you try `{{ data }}`?

Comment: yes I already tried that, throws an error "Notice array to string conversion"

Comment: i tried {{ data|json_encode() }}, the data shows in browser console, but show error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{{ data|json_encode|raw }}`. By default Twig will escape any content for HTML, the `|raw` filter prevents that.

Also if you're running into an issue where the `json_encode` call is creating a JavaScript object `{}` rather than an array `[]`, just call `array_merge` on your data before passing it to Twig:

```
$data = array_merge($data);
```

This will rekey the array to use numeric indices and will correctly be transformed into a JavaScript array when using `json_encode`.